# Set launchd log level

Tags: macos, launchd

How can I set the log level of launchd in MacOS Yosemite?

I've tried `launchctl log level debug` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142

Comment: @sdmeyers I want to debug launchd itself (know what is doing, if it is crashing, who is requesting which jobs to get started when, what are those jobs doing, are they crashing? are they spamming request to start other jobs that are constantly dying?)

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. The `log` command isn't implemented in the latest version of `launchctl`. the `examine` subcommand will allow to profile a a fork of `launched`

Comment: `Usage: launchctl examine [<tool> [arg0, arg1, ... , @PID, ...]]
With no arguments, causes launchd to fork(2) itself for examination by
subsequent analysis tools and prints the PID of this instance to stdout.`  This is hardly an alternative to generalized debug logging of `launchd`.  If this doesn't get answered, I'm adding a bounty.

Comment: Consider asking this on the [`launchd` developer mailing list](https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/launchd-dev); members of the list include the authors of `launchd`.

Comment: it seems that i cannot use examine on the mac, it says that it  is only available in the DEVELOPMENT variant :/

Comment: did anyone figure out an answer here?  i've just subscribed to the mailing list.

Comment: Is it possible to debug an application that you don't have source to?

Comment: Try [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33259)

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple publishes the source code for launchd, you might have better luck just attaching a debugger to the process to inspect or set breakpoints.

That and changing the log level might also be overkill. You can inspect the loaded jobs quite easily and disable them / change them to call debugging scripts or even set another job to dump status or log messages when another process starts or stops.

I'd be interested in more specifics of what you are doing - this seems like a great example of an XY problem. You're asking about the solution you see as the best way forward and not about what the actual problem / issue is.

Comment: Try starting apache with a garbage configuration. On linux it will complain and a detailed error will be in `systemctl status httpd`. On mac, you seem to be out of luck. With a vague error such as `(homebrew.mxcl.httpd24[36144]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1`